# Spring setter injection guarantee

Tags: java, spring

Is it safe to move form constructor injection to setter injection ?

Does setter injection guarantee that my object is fully constructed at usage time?

Comment: Both injections guarantee that. The injection in the constructor, however, can have some limitations related to circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe.

**With constructor injection**, Spring will call the constructor with appropriate arguments (note that in this case you can add the `final` modifier to your dependencies field).

Sample

```
private final SomeBean dependency;

public MyObject(SomeBean dependency){
    this.dependency = dependency;
    doInit();
}

private void doInit(){
    //doStuff to initialize your bean
}
```

**With setter injection**, Spring will instantiate your bean using the default constructor (i.e. no arg constructor).
Next step is calling all required setters so that all @Autowired dependencies are set.
Finally Spring will call methods with @PostConstruct annotation.

Sample

```
@Autowired
private SomeBean dependency;

@PostConstruct
private void doInit(){
    //doStuff to initialize your bean
}
```

Using setter injection have one advantage: in case of circular dependencies between your beans, Spring will be able to resolve them (because it can invoke a setter with a *partially build bean*). (it's ok if your setters are real setters and do anything more than assigning a value to a field)

On the other hand, Spring fails to resolve circular dependencies when using constructor injection, simply because a *partially build bean* cannot decently be used as constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but here are my 2 cents in 2 points,

- In any OO language [setter/field injection is evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/).
- It is better to fail fast due to a Circular dependency Injection, as it is a design error. And not noticing them could adversely affect you latter on.